# theano.scan: Non-unit value on shape on a broadcastable dimension

Tags: python, theano

I am developing a very simple program which uses `theano.scan` function to loop through an array of vectors (in the end, I intend to develop a LSTM layer for my program). The problem is that I always get the error `Non-unit on shape of a broadcastable dimension` when compiling the function. I believe the `updates` param is the cause because as long as I put it there to compile a function, the error will occur. Here is the code:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from utils import *
import numpy as np

class LSTM:
    def __init__(self, X, in_size, out_size):
        self.X = X
        self.in_size = in_size
        self.out_size = out_size
        self.W_x = init_weights((in_size, out_size), "W_x")

        def _active(x, pre_h):
            x = T.reshape(x, (1, in_size))
            pre_h = T.dot(x, self.W_x)
            return pre_h

        h, updates = theano.scan(_active, sequences=X,
            outputs_info = [T.alloc(floatX(0.), 1, out_size)])

        self.activation = h

if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = T.matrix('X')
    in_size = 2
    out_size = 4
    lstm = LSTM(X, in_size, out_size)
    value = lstm.activation
    cost = T.mean(value)
    params = [lstm.W_x]

    updates = []
    for p in params:
        gp = T.grad(cost, p)
        updates.append((p, p - 0.1*gp))

    f = theano.function([X], outputs = cost, updates=updates)

    test = f(np.random.rand(10, in_size))
    print test
```

In the code, I use some functions loaded from `utils.py`, which is like this:

```
#pylint: skip-file
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

def floatX(X):
    return np.asarray(X, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

def init_weights(shape, name):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.random.randn(*shape) * 0.1), name)

def init_gradws(shape, name):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.zeros(shape)), name)

def init_bias(size, name):
    return theano.shared(floatX(np.zeros((size,))), name)
```

I have been searching for a while but could not find any solution for this problem. In addition, I can not see any problem with my code. If I do not use `theano.scan`, the code will be running just fine.

Can you see any problem in my code? Do you have any advice to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am able to run your exact same code without any problems ...

Comment: Also, this might be helpful for you:
https://github.com/uyaseen/theano-recurrence/blob/master/model/lstm.py

Comment: @uyaseen oh really, Which version of theano are you using? I want to check if it is an issue of theano version

Comment: I have theano 0.7.0.dev